# DATEPART to calculate financial year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a report that uses the `DATPART()` function to return the current, and previous, year's data:

```
DATEPART(YEAR, a.Date);
DATEPART(YEAR, a.Date) = DATPART(YEAR, GetDate())-1
```

This brings through calendar year fine.
Is it possible to amend this to bring through the financial year (e.g. `1/4/15 - 31/3/16`)?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Use `DATEADD` and don't subtract -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily build a function that will return the fiscal year of any date by testing on MONTH() value. It might look like this:

```
CASE WHEN MONTH(a.date)>3 
THEN YEAR(a.Date) 
ELSE YEAR(a.Date) -1
END
```

If needed, YEAR(a.date) can be replaced by DATEPART(YEAR,a.date)